# Session after login and the possible of hacking

Tags: asp-classic, session-variables

I want to know once and for all

in classic ASP!

if i have a form like this

```
<form action="login.asp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
<input type="password" name="password" value="" />
</form>
```

and in the login.asp page i check if the username and password are correct i give a session("loggedin") a value

then in everypage i check for that session and for that value

my question - is that the right, most common secure thing to do??? or i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I am finally moving to .Net (Good and bad...I loved Classic ASP), but how I handled it in classic ASP to make it manageable is:

Create an include file, like this:

```
if (nz(session("users.userid"))=0) then
    'PUT YOUR LOGIN CODE HERE
    session("users.userid") = userId
else
    'CODE TO DISPLAY LOGIN FORM
    response.end
end if
```

Include this at the top of every page that should be secure. If they haven't logged in, it will throw the login form. Obviously you can make this more useful than this, but this is as clearly as I could explain it.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty standard, you can use SSL in conjunction with that for better security.  Also you could have another session value/cookie that is a hash of the user's IP address and some other secret value and check the IP addresses each request.

Comment: two questions: what about hijeck or hack of a server session variable? second: if i have his ip in the form and then i check it in the server side as hash - it will always be the same, won't it?

Comment: Yes the IP will be the same, but if you hash the remote IP along with a secret value, then an attacker should not be able to spoof that value without knowing the secret value.  The SSL is what helps prevent the hijack.  At least nothing in the middle or on the network could easily sniff the browser traffic and see the value.

Comment: can you give me an example for that combination of ip and secret value?

Comment: I'm not sure what hashing functions you have in ASP classic, but when the user logs in you could set a session variable or cookie with the value Hash = SHA1(User_Ip & "somereallylongstringthatnooneknows.")  Then they have to send that value back with each request and you take the remote IP address and hash it against the same secret and make sure its the same as the cookie/session value.  The idea is that a malicious user who hijacked the session should not be able to forge the IP cookie so if the IP doesn't match, you can log them out or ask to re-enter the password.