# Force login in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have make a login page  in asp classic named SiteMaster.asp

i have set this page as default page thats work fine , but if an user knows

tha name of the other pages can access without login , example

```
http://localhost/teste/barra.asp
```

what i need to add for block this kind o access?

this is the code of my login page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Intranet Novo Macuco </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head><body>
<form name="login" method="post" action="verify.asp" >
<table >
<tr> 
<td height="49" colspan="5"><p><img src="imagens/moveisnovomacuco.PNG" width="226" height="95"  alt=""/></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p></td>
</tr>
<tr> 

<td >Login</td>
<td colspan="3" ><input type="text" name="loginx" id="login"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Senha</td>
<td colspan="3" ><input type="password" name="passx" id="passwordx"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar"></td>
<td colspan="3" ><input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Limpar"> 
 </td>

</table>
</form>
</body></html>
```

I need to user session or another object to make this???

Comment: You will need to make sure Session State is enabled then you can set a Session variable to store the user id. You can then check the Session variable in other pages to make sure the session hasn't timed out *(default is 20 minutes in IIS)*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session after login and the possible of hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439875/session-after-login-and-the-possible-of-hacking)